# How to save arrayof Seekbars position and its Visibility throuhout App

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer, android-seekbar

I am using Exoplayer to play multiple audios simultaneously and appoint each audio its own sound Control.

but if we move to another Activity and return, our Seekbars were gone,
how we can resolve this?

sounds are still playing but our seekbars are not.

as given here.

I also have a small demo app on which you can test the behavior: [FeatureApp](https://github.com/th3kumar/Feature).

[image]

how I am using buttons

```
 play_rain.setOnClickListener {
            playerService?.toggleSound(PlayerService.Sound.RAIN)
            toggleProgressBar(rain_volume)
        }
```

toggleProgressBar

```
private fun toggleProgressBar(progressBar: ProgressBar) {
        progressBar.visibility = if (progressBar.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE
    }
```

other onCreate Services

```
 override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val playerIntent = Intent(this, PlayerService::class.java)
        startService(playerIntent)
        bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        unbindService(serviceConnection)
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        playerService?.stopForeground()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        playerService?.startForeground()
        super.onPause()
    }
```

FloatingActionButton

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
            playerService?.stopPlaying()
            fab.hide()
            // hide all volume bars
            arrayOf(rain_volume, storm_volume, water_volume, fire_volume, wind_volume, night_volume, cat_volume).forEach { bar ->
                bar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you return to first activity then your activity is recreated as it was killed when it was not the top activity. What happens if you rotate the device instead?

Comment: not rotating, orientation is portrait only

Comment: Well for testing allow landscape too and solve rotation handling.

Comment: Maybe you should consider `onSaveInstanceState` and using the `savedInstanceState` Bundle in your activity's `onCreate`

Comment: @el_chupacabra how can I save more than 1 seekbars states in onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: It is a [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) you can add as many to it as you'd like.